# Javascript Invalid left-hand side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an error here $('#cps').val() = time;.

The thing is, I'm not trying to compare it, I'm trying to set the the value of cps to the variable time.

```
var amount = 0;
$("#cps").click(function() {
    amount = amount + 1;
    console.log(amount);
    setInterval(function() {
        countDown()
    }, 1000);
    console.log(time);
});

var time = 30;

function countDown() {
    time = (parseInt(time) - 1).toString();
    $('#cps').val() = time;

}
```

Comment: `$('#cps').val(time);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method act as a getter and setter function, if you don't pass any parameter to it, .val() will return the value but if you pass a parameter to it, the function will try to set the passed value

```
$('#cps').val(time);
```

Comment: Oops, still thinking in C#